# Nginx causes static build of React app to break

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I'm trying to serve a static build of a ReactJS app using Nginx, but something really strange is happening: the stylesheet isn't getting applied and the image isn't loading. I can see in the developer tools that the resources are there (see the image below), they just aren't getting applied. However, the javascript file is running--otherwise there wouldn't be any content on the screen.

[image: screenshot of website with developer tools]

What makes this even weirder is that I tried serving the files in the same directory using a python http server (command: `python3 -m http.server 80`), and it was fine; all of the assets loaded correctly.

Since it seems to be an nginx issue, here's my nginx config:

nginx.conf

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    # Http redirect to https (unless it's a challenge)
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name ambitx.io www.ambitx.io wc.ambitx.io rk.ambitx.io;
        server_tokens off;

        include letsencrypt.conf;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
    }

    # React frontend
    server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name ambitx.io www.ambitx.io;
        
        include ssl.conf;
        include letsencrypt.conf;
        
        location / {
            root /var/www/staticfiles;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }
    }

    # Websocket backend
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        
        server_name wc.ambitx.io;

        include ssl.conf;
        include letsencrypt.conf;

        location / {
            proxy_pass "http://wsserver:8080";
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }

    # Rocket backend
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name rk.ambitx.io;

        include ssl.conf;
        include letsencrypt.conf;

        location / {
            proxy_pass "http://rocketserver:80";
        }
    }
}
```

letsencrypt.conf

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
}
```

ssl.conf

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ambitx.io/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ambitx.io/privkey.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # don't use SSLv3. Ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: it turns out the Nginx server was missing it's MIME types (the browser thought that the css file was `text/plain` instead of `text/css`).

Usually the best practice is to add files to */etc/nginx/conf.d/* (and mount your docker volume there) instead of editting *nginx.conf* directly, but I wanted to be able to place other files in the */etc/nginx/* directory so I decided to mount my docker volume there.

As it turns out, that's a *bad idea*. I overwrote a lot of other important config files inside the docker container. Now, I could just copy all of those files into my docker volume and call it good, but I decided it would be worth doing it the "right" way so I don't mess up stuff in the future.

So, now I have a docker volume mounted at */etc/nginx/cond.f/* and another volume mounted at */etc/nginx/lib/* so that I can import files without the main *nginx.conf* reading is as a server config.